# Upload Trivy result.json file to DefectDojo

Tags: devops, application-security, devsecops, trivy

I am using trivy to do docker scanning and then saving the output into `result.json` file. Now I am trying to send the file to [DefectDojo](https://github.com/DefectDojo/django-DefectDojo) to visualize it there, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Products"
, Select a product,
in the "Findings" tab > "Import Scan Results"

or use API:
create an engagement:

```
curl -X POST   "https://dojo:8080/api/v2/engagements/" -H "Authorization: Token <your token>"  -F "name=Test" -F "product=<Product ID>" -F "target_start=2022-06-14" -F "target_end=2022-06-14"
```

Import Scan:

```
 curl -X POST "https://dojo:8080/api/v2/import-scan/" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "Content-Type: multipart/form-data"  -H "Authorization: Token <your token>" -F "minimum_severity=Info" -F "active=true" -F "verified=true" -F "scan_type=Trivy Scan" -F "close_old_findings=false" -F "push_to_jira=false" -F "file=@result.json" -F "product_name=Test" -F "scan_date=2022-06-14" -F "engagement_name=Test"
```

Answer (score 0):

There's another problem with DefectDojo's importer for Trivy:
They parse only CVEs, but trivy can find secrets as well.

Try this tool as well:
https://docs.whitespots.io/appsec-portal/install/deployment-guide/installation